# Django - HTML template form does not pass content to django view

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a Django application, but I have an Issue that template doesn't pass it's content to view.

this is my form..

```
  <form action="{% url 'view-job' %}" method="post" enctype=application/x-www-form-urlencoded>
{% csrf_token %}
<div>
  <label for="name">Job name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="name" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="owner">Owner: </label>
  <input type="text" id="owner" />
</div>
...
```

and this is my post handling view (views_job.py)

```
def job(request, pk=None):
if request.method == 'GET':
    return get(request, pk)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    return post(request)
   ...
```

and post(request)

```
def post(request):
    #data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    #data = load_json(request)
    new_job = create_new_job(request)
    #new_job = create_new_job(request)
    if new_job != False:
        return new_job
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=500)
```

create_new_job(req)

```
def create_new_job(req):
    config = parse_config()

    try:
        queryset = Job.objects.create(
            name=req.POST.get('name'),
            owner=req.POST.get('owner'),
            execute_date=req.POST.get('execute_date'),
            created_date=timezone.now(),
            master=req.POST.get('master') if 'master' in req.POST != None else config[DEFAULT][MASTER],
            deploy_mode=req.POST.get('deploy_mode') if 'deploy_mode' in req.POST != None else config[DEFAULT][DEPLOY_MODE],
            conf=req.POST.get('conf'),
            classpath=req.POST.get('classpath'),
            app_arguments=req.POST.get('app_arguments'),
            user_params=req.POST.get('user_params'),
            status=READY,
        )
        #queryset.save()
    except:
        print("Error")
        print(req.POST.get('name'))
        return False

    return render(req, 'jobUI/job_details.html',
                    {
                        #'job':queryset
                    }
                )
```

The console prints

```
INFO 2018-03-21 18:48:29,033 basehttp 1321 140106696156928 "GET /jobUI/job/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1799
INFO 2018-03-21 18:48:30,208 basehttp 1321 140106696156928 "GET /jobUI/job/newjob/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1620
Error
None
ERROR 2018-03-21 18:48:47,499 basehttp 1321 140106696156928 "POST /jobUI/job/ HTTP/1.1" 500 0
```

I don't know why request.POST['name'] is None and other things too..

How can I fix it?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `input` fields don't have a `name` attribute; without that the browser won't send any data.

Note, you should really be using the Django forms framework for this. And you certainly absolutely shouldn't have a blank `except` clause.

Comment: I'm very appriciate :). I tried to use django form so I made forms.py but It wasn't work very well, so I just made this naive(?) html page for test of my views and.. I have to study more, I think. Thank you.